# Powershell hashtable creation - Foreach loop

Tags: powershell, dictionary, hash, active-directory

I am trying to create a hashtable/dictionary (kvp), within powershell, for further usage (for excel addition). However I am getting object-based error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as the workflow seem to match and connect in my head.

Code:

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com" | select-object name
foreach ($name in $users) {
    $hash = [ordered]@{ $name = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $name | Select-Object name) }
}
$hash
```

Error:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot create object of type
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal". The adapter cannot set the value of property "name".
At line:2 char:56
+     $hash = @{ $name = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $name | Select ...
+                                                        ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrinci
   palGroupMembership
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try with **samaccountname** instead of **name**?

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=sectest,DC=secservizi,DC=local" | select-object samaccountname
foreach ($name in $users.samaccountname) {
    $hash = [ordered]@{ $name = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity $name | Select-Object name) }  
}
$hash
```

Comment: Hii you are partially correct If I can say so. I used this to get the desired output: 

`$usersAMAccName = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com" | select-object sAMAccountName
$hash.Clear()
$data = @('Name', 'Email', 'Organizational Unit')
$data += @(Get-ADGroup -filter * -searchbase "OU=Groups,DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com" |  Select-Object -expandproperty name )
foreach ($name in $usersAMAccName) {
    $hash += [ordered]@{ $name.sAMAccountName = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $name.sAMAccountName | select-object name).name }

}`